# Which firebase value from firebase-auth to use as uid in my own database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase auth and I need to store the authenticated user in my own User table (I only plan to use firebase auth, and not their backend services). However, I'm unsure which value provided by firebase should be used as the unique identifier.

In the docs, Firebase states:

```
 uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                   // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                   // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
```

According to that comment above (seen here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) that mean that I can't rely on the `uid`?

Are they saying I should use

```
 user.getIdToken().then((token) => {
  // is this my UUID that I should store in my own db
  // this one? Its 926 characters long, 
  console.log(token);
 });
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that although you might not want to use some of the other Firebase products, you may find it more performant to host your service within the realm of the Google Cloud Platform to help reduce network latency when authenticating to your backend. IMO Cloud Run is particularly good product for APIs and works very well with Firebase Auth.

Comment: ELI5? Not sure what you mean by

`more performant to host your service within the realm of the Google Cloud Platform to help reduce network latency`

What service?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a frontend application to which you authenticate. Since you're choosing not to use Firebase Functions or call Firestore directly from your client app you will need to provide some backend functionality by some other means, typically using an API service?

Comment: Yes. I plan on using Django (as a rest api for my nuxt front end) and a Postgres db on the backend. The only reason I turned to firebase is because auth on SPAs are a pain to set up IMO

Comment: I wrote my answer using JavaScript as that was the only tag available in the question. You will need to adjust the example below to use the Python equivilent on your server side code https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#verify_id_token

Comment: This video just got published on YouTube a few minutes ago. This is the scenario you are looking for https://youtu.be/4HAbnin3nto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use the UID as the unique key for per-user data in your database.  That's what way it's intended to be used.

I think you might be misinterpreting the comment.  The problem that it's trying to address is sending the UID **to your own backend** via an API call. That call could be faked by anyone who knows how to call the API endpoint, which means they could send any UID they want.  For those cases, the client app is supposed to instead supply an ID token to the back for it to validate with the Firebase Admin SDK.  This is the only secure way to send information about the user for your backend so that it can't be hacked.

If you aren't sending the UID to a backend, then you don't need to send a token and validate it.  If you are simply using the UID locally or through other Firebase products that implement security rules, you don't need to worry about tokens at all.

Answer (score 4):

Key your own user table using the Firebase Auth `user.uid`.

**Client side:**

Your web application runs in your end-user's browser and makes use of the Firebase Client SDK. For example, an email and password signin might look something like this:

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((user) => {
    // Signed in 
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_in_existing_users

Behind the scenes the browser gets a JWT from the Firebase Auth Service. Each hour the tokens are renewed and you can get these by using an event listener.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
    // Get the JWT (see line below)
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

From the user object you can get hold of the JWT (stored in the client's browser).

```js
const jwt = await getIdToken().token;
```

(Note, I've mixed async/await style and .then paradigms here, so you will need to pick one).

Once your have a JWT you use this to call your backend service, typically sending it within the header of an HTTP request.

*Server side:*

Extract the JWT from the HTTP request header into `idToken` and then verify the token using `verifyIdToken(idToken)`. This method runs in a privileged environment (Admin SDK). Behind the scenes the verifyIdToken contacts the Firebase Auth Service to authenticate the JWT. The Firebase Auth Service *is* hosted within Google's infrastructure but you have no access to it direct- only via the verifyIdToken call.

You should *not* be storing JWTs inside your database as they are regenerated hourly by the Firebase Auth Client.

Once authenticated by your backend you can extract the uid from the JWT.

```js
// idToken comes from the client app
admin
  .auth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((decodedToken) => {
    const uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk

Comment: Why would I need to verify the idtoken myself? Thats handled by firebase upon successful email/password login?

This is the reason I use firebase - to not have to do that whole verification myself

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Even though it’s not 100% related to my question it’s super valuable and I’ll probably come back to it soon.